# UITextView contents not being localized

Tags: ios7, nslocalizedstring, xcode5.1

I have an iPad app (XCode 5.1, iOS 7.0, ARC, Storyboards).  I have a UITextView in one of my UIViews.  If I put text in the UITextView, it won't localize (at least that's been my experience).  So, I did the following, placing this code in the **viewDidLoad** method for that page:

```
oMessage.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Tell us how we can make this a better app by leaving feedback.  If you leave your email address, we will respond to your request.  ",nil);

[super viewDidLoad];
```

One of the LocalizedStrings looks like this (and it is a match with what's in code):

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell us how we can make this a better app by leaving feedback.  If you leave your email address, we will respond to your request.  "
 = "我々はフィードバックを残すことで、この優れたアプリを作ることができる方法を教えてください。あなたのメールアドレスのままにしておくと、私たちはあなたの要求に応答します。";
```

When I run the app, it doesn't show any localization for any language.  Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Comment: What does your `Localizable.string` file looks like? Does `oMessage == nil` when you try to set the text?

Comment: Did you change the setting of the language of your device? Or are you trying to run on simulator? Does your text show the "key", or another translation?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the setting for the language using the Scheme... results are the same simulator or device... text shows the key (or the English translation)... doesn't find the key to search for the translation.

Comment: What it's looking like is that **NONE** of the **Localizable.strings** are being localized! In other words, it's as if the Localizable.strings files don't exist...

Comment: did you add the language localization to the project file? under the info tab you can add another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!  I didn't copy the Localizable.strings files in the Build Phase... Stupid mistake!

Thanks for the help... I appreciate your time... SD